# Must declare the scalar variable, but they exist in markup

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sqldatasource

I have an SqlDataSource that i'm using for a GridView. I have used the Delete functionality of the GridView the same as iv used it for the Update function on other ones, but for some reason this is telling me that my parameters have not been declared. Youll see in code that I put them there, I just copied them from the Update Parameters. I am stumped as to why sql is telling me I hav enot declared the variable when they are clearly there.

Thanks

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceVisitors" runat="server" ConnectionString="connstring" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [RegisteredVisitors] WHERE [PK] = @PK; UPDATE [dbo].[Users] SET [NumberOfVisitors] = (SELECT [NumberOfVisitors] FROM [dbo].[NumberOfVisitors] WHERE [ResidentName] = @ResidentName) -1 WHERE [ResidentName] = @ResidentName" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [RegisteredVisitors] ([ResidentName], [ResidentAddress], [VisitorCode], [VisitorName]) VALUES (@ResidentName, @ResidentAddress, @VisitorCode, @VisitorName)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [RegisteredVisitors] WHERE ([ResidentName] = @ResidentName)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [RegisteredVisitors] SET [ResidentName] = @ResidentName, [ResidentAddress] = @ResidentAddress, [VisitorCode] = @VisitorCode, [VisitorName] = @VisitorName WHERE [PK] = @PK" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="PK" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ResidentName" Type="String" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ResidentName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ResidentAddress" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="VisitorCode" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="VisitorName" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtboxSelectedResident" Name="ResidentName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ResidentName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ResidentAddress" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="VisitorCode" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="VisitorName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PK" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I don't see a ResidentName in the DeleteCommand. `DELETE FROM [RegisteredVisitors] WHERE [PK] = @PK;`

Comment: Its after the ";". the rest of that statement i just ended up taking out. I don't know why it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Check your syntax, your Delete command has an error:

```
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [RegisteredVisitors] WHERE [PK] = @PK 
UPDATE [dbo].[Users] SET [NumberOfVisitors] = (SELECT [NumberOfVisitors] FROM [dbo].[NumberOfVisitors] WHERE [ResidentName] = @ResidentName) -1 WHERE [ResidentName] = @ResidentName"
```

If you are trying to execute more than one query, you need to separate them with a ";"